# Is there any function or method like subprocess.getoutput() in c or c++?

Tags: c++, c, python-3.x

Python:

```
print("Active Device:"+subprocess.getoutput("ip link|grep \"state UP\"|cut -d : -f 2|cut -d \' \' -f2"))
```

Can I get output like That⬆ in c by doing this?:
C:

```
printf("Active Device:%s",getsystemoutput("ip link|grep \"state UP\"|cut -d : -f 2|cut -d \' \' -f2"));
```

Comment: Which are you interested in?  C or C++?  These are different languages.

Comment: In C you have to read command output manually. Look for `popen()`

Comment: In C++ I would recommend looking at Boost::Process which has ways of doing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function `getsystemoutput()` could look like follows:

```
char *getsystemoutput( char *cmd )
{
    static char output[1024];

    FILE *fp;

    if( (fp = popen( cmd, "r" )) == NULL )
        return "";

    if( fgets( outout, sizeof output, fp ) == NULL )
        strcpy( output, "" );

    pclose( fp );
    return output;
}
```

This version returns an empty string in case of error and uses a static buffer for output, which makes it easy to use in a `printf()` but for general purpose I would suggest to return NULL on errors and pass `output` + it's size as arguments. You might also want to check for the result of `pclose()` to determine the exit status of the command called. And be aware that without a loop, it will only return the first line of output.

Answer (score 1):

Standard C has no function to run an external process, collect its standard output and standard error, and return that as a string.  In fact, as a matter of policy, standard C does not provide functions that return dynamically-allocated memory, which such a function would need to do, other than its functions than have allocating memory as their express purpose.

In a POSIX environment, you can rely on `popen()` to provide a `FILE *` by which you can read the standard output of a shell command:

```
FILE *file = popen("ip link | grep 'state UP' | cut -d : -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f2",
                   "r"));

if (file == NULL) {
    // handle error
}
```

You'll then have to handle reading the output yourself; perhaps via `fgets()`:

```
char buffer[LARGE_ENOUGH];

// Read one line from the input (or part of one, if the buffer is too small)
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) == NULL) {
    // handle error
}
// If a newline was read then it will be included
buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
```

You can print the result:

```
printf("Active Device:%s", buffer);
```

Remember that a file opened with `popen()` must be closed with `pclose()`:

```
if (pclose(file) != 0) {
    // handle error
}
```

Note, by the way, that if you want to capture the stderr as well as the standard output, as your Python version does, then your best bet is to accommodate that via I/O redirection in the command, such as:

```
FILE *file = popen(
        "{ ip link | grep 'state UP' | cut -d : -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f2; } 2>&1",
        "r"));
```